# What are pseudo classes and what are they used for?

Tags: css

I am very new here. I've seen many questions and their answers. But I have a question since I opened a blog website.
My question is What are pseudo classes and what are they used for?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Since pseudo-classes have nothing to do with PHP, performance, or jQuery, I've removed those tags from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo classes are things like `:active` and `:hover` which refer to a transient state. For instance:

```
div {
    color: black;
}
div:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

With that, a `div` element will have black text normally, but blue text when you hover the mouse over it.

Hovering is just one example. There are pseudo-classes for:

- `:hover` - Hovering
- `:active` - The active element on a page
- `:focus` - The element with focus
- `:link` and `:visited` - For links so you can style visited ones differently from unvisited ones
- `:checked`, `:disabled` - For styling form controls based on state
- A bunch of structural ones, like `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `:nth-child` for an element's position in its parent's child list
- ...and various others

More about them [in the CSS selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).